# click button from screen print

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework

Big Doubt:
Sikuli Library with Robot Framework has some keyword that takes the print of my screen and, from the print, I click on a button
provided in another saved image?

Reason for the question: I have a screen with more than 4 equal buttons. I need to click on the 4th button. How do I click the position four button?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Click Nth](http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html#Click%20Nth), and if that is not the solution, then you need to get images coordinates and do some calculation to where to click.